# i got an error of missing right paranthesis in the sub query

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SQL> update client set cname='unknown client' where clientno=(select clientno from client order by clientno asc);
```

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
 it giving missing right paranthesids in the order by sub query.

```
SQL> update client set cname='unknown client' where clientno=(select clientno from client order by clientno asc);
```

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

```
SQL> update client set cname='unknown client' where clientno=(select clientno from client order by clientno asc);
```

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Comment: This doesn't look right to me: `where clientno=(select clientno from client order by clientno asc)`. based on the `order by` clause, do you mean to be only taking the first record by clientno? if so, you'll need a `top` clause. if there could be multiple matches, you'll want `in`, not equals. Can you provide more information on what you're trying to do here?

Comment: The error is from having an order-by clause in the subquery. That doesn't make sense, logically, and is invalid. (Though Oracle does allow it in some contexts, even where it's pointless. Not here though.) What are you actually trying to do - update only the client with the highest (or lowest) number? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You are updating all records, so simplify to:

```
 update client set cname='unknown client';
```

Comment: I'm skeptical that's the intent here, more likely an incorrectly-formed WHERE clause. But more information from OP would definitely help.